# How to dim or blur other collection view when I tap and hold particular view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 6 grids of Collection View, it is on 2 rows and 3 columns. Is there any trick to make 5 others Collection View blur or dim if I tap and hold one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first you need a way to blur the other collectionViewCells. If you do not already have an implementation, I would just search for 'blur' on github and look at swift/objective-c repositories. Ensure that every cell contains the blurView as the topmost view and then activate it on all of the cells within the visibleCells array of the UICollectionView (except the selected one ofcourse).

To emulate something like force touch, I would also transform the size of the cell that is selected to make it larger. You can slowly increase the blur/size while the user is holding their finger and create a nice effect.